# Dapper Extensions - change primary key field

Tags: dapper

We are thinking of switching over to Dapper from EF.  I'd like to use the Dapper Extensions to populate my entities like:

```
UserInstance = conn.Get(UserProfile)(RecordID)
```

All of our primary key columns are named RecordID but preceeded by Parent_RecordID.  The Get tries to use Parent_RecordID as my primary key column, "If multiple properties end with Id, Dapper Extensions will use the first Id property as the primary key."

How can I change this so it looks for RecordID as my primary key only for every table?  I understand I can create my own mapper for entity but I want this change to apply to every table(there are 100's of them) and would rather not create a mapper for every one of them.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried creating a mapping class for the entity?

```
public class UserProfileMapper : ClassMapper<UserProfile>
{
    public UserProfileMapper()
    {
    Table("UserProfile");
    Map(f => f.RecordID).Key(KeyType.Identity);
    ...
    }
}
```

Not sure if the mapper class is used for a Get.

Comment: That's kind of what I want but I want it to apply to all of my tables.  There 100's of tables and I don't want to create a new mapper for all of them.

Comment: You can provide your own mapping class https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/AutoClassMapper

Comment: hm... I want to use ClassMapper but can't find it inside the library.

Answer (score 1):

You can the directive `[Key]` above the primary key of each table

Comment: He is talking about dapper extensions. AFAIK, it does not support directives/attributes. It supports mapping classes instead.